# Databaselink & Instead of Trigger

Tags: database, oracle, triggers, hyperlink

i've the following task to manage.
We have a database link between server 'A' and server 'B'.
I created tables on Server 'A' and Views on server 'B' pointing to these tables.

I.Ex.
a table customers on server 'A'
and a view customers on server 'B' pointing to the table on server 'A'.

To provide update capability on the view I created an Instead of Update trigger on the view:

```
PROMPT CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tudb_customers
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tudb_customers instead of update or delete on customers
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
for each row

declare
proc_typ_old char;
proc_typ char;
begin
if updating then
    proc_typ := 'U';
else
    proc_typ := 'D';
end if;

if proc_typ = 'U' then
    update customers@db_link set customersname=:new.customersname
    where customersid = :old.customersid;
else
delete from customers@db_link where customersid = :old.customersid;
end if;
end TUDB_MOB_ZUG;
/
```

If I try to update the view on server 'B' (update customers set customersname = 'Henry' where customersid = 1) the :old.customersid is always null. So update fails.

Oracleversion is 10.2.0.1.0

Can anyone help me in this matter? Any ideas?

Greetings,
Chris

Comment: Is there any reason for not creaintg the view on the the same server where the table is?

Comment: yes there is. The server B is on the customers side. So all their client pc's are able to connect to our server using the views

Comment: If I were you, I would recreate the view (and the triger) on server 'A', without the dblink of course, and would give it a try if it works. I understand it is not feasible because of the client PC's etc. Just to make sure it is not because of the dblink.

Comment: yeah that's working. So problem is the link it seems?

Comment: update customers@db_link set customersname='Henry'
    where customersid = 1 is working aswell.
Only the trigger seems not to get the :old.customersid and fails.

Comment: FWIW, works for me with 10.2.0.5, so possibly you're hitting a bug in the base version? Just to clarify, are you debugging to see that `:old` is null, or assuming it it because the update doesn't do anything? (Possibly bug 4771052 if that's the case, fixed in 10.2.0.3?)

Comment: no I put it into an dbms output. And it says it's null

Comment: Related bug 4386090 sounds like `:old` values are null within the trigger if it has a DB link. Think you're going to need to raise an SR with Oracle, though I suspect they might advise to patch up.

Comment: oh thank you very much. It's a bug then. You should post your comment as reply

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be a bug, since it seems to work OK in 10.2.0.5. Bug 4386090 ('OLD VALUE RETURN NULL IN "INSTEAD OF" TRIGGER BASED ON DBLINK) sounds from the diagnostic analysis like `:old` values are null within the trigger if it has a DB link; that seems to have been closed as a duplicate of 4771052 ('INSTEAD-OF trigger does not update tables correctly over dblink', but can't see more details), which is listed in the 10.2.0.3 patchset notes.

You will need to raise an SR with Oracle to confirm this is the same issue, though if it is I suspect they won't do more than advise you to patch up since 10g has been out of support for a while. No workarounds are listed unfortunately.

If the view is of a single table, which seems to be the case from your initial description, I'm not sure you even need the trigger; updating and deleting work directly. Does your view [require an INSTEAD OF trigger](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_triggers.htm#i1025919)?

Comment: yes cause I am not able to update the table directly. As far as I know you can't update a view without an instead of trigger ?!

Comment: @Chris - you can for simple views; the link at the end of the answer shows the scenarios where you can't update directly, and have to use a trigger. If you've tried and get an error then yours may be more complicated than the question suggests.

Answer (score 0):

A agree with @AlexPoole, on that this well may be a bug and you're probably will be advised to apply a patch upon contacting to Oracle.

Good point also, updating via the view may not be necessary in your case.

However at this point if I were you, I would contemplate whether this is a good way to establish connection between the clients and the database. I mean connecting an Oracle instance (server 'B') via dblink to the real db instance (server 'A') and letting clients connect to real server indirectly via server 'B'. I think it is kind of a hack that at a certain moment seems to be an easy way to solve something which is probably a networking issue, but later cases further problems, like this time.

Comment: no it's not a network issue. Server 'B' isn't part of our local network. It's located at our customers firm and all the customers client pcs should be able to connect to Server 'A' which is located at our firm. We have a VPN-TUNNEL between Server 'A' and Server 'B' and we want to avoid buying additional vpn-licenses for each of the customers client pcs to establish the connection directly. So my projection was that Server 'B' redirects all queries to Server 'A'.